# Update ListView in fragment from locking mechanism locks UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview

I have a *ListView* that I want to update with messages coming from a Bluetooth socket. The ListView is in a fragment, this does not matter too much.

The problem comes when I want to listen to incoming messages from the socket (which is a locking mechanism on a separate thread) and update the ListView with the received message.
**FChat.java**

```
public class FChat extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    ....
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //setup list view
        ListView messageContainer = (ListView) thisView.findViewById(R.id.btMessagesContainer);
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(thisView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        currentAct = getActivity();
        Thread test = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                try {
                    currentAct.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listItems.add("other:" + String.valueOf(times));
                            try {
                                String reply = bluetoothConnector.readSingleMessage();
                                listItems.add("other:" + reply);
                                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    };
    test.start();            

    }
}
```

So, this feels like it's blocking the UI thread completely, so I guess that runOnUiThread it's blocking the UI thread. 

If I take out the blocking part 
`String reply = bluetoothConnector.readSingleMessage();` and replace it with `String reply = "test"` it works fine, the UI is updated and seems to work great.

So, my question is, how can I read data from a socket and update the ListView with its contents?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it **blocks** `UI thread`.

How your code looks like in pseudo:

```
Thread {
    //there is separate thread
    UiThread{
       //there is UI thread
       blockingOperation()
    }
}
```

In other words your current thread is almost useless since you do blocking operation in UI thread.

And for sure it works with

```
String reply = "test"
```

Because that is not blocking operation.

So to solute problem just move

```
String reply = bluetoothConnector.readSingleMessage();
```

inside **separate** thread:

```
Thread test = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
            try {
                final String reply = bluetoothConnector.readSingleMessage();
                currentAct.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listItems.add("other:" + String.valueOf(times));
                        listItems.add("other:" + reply);
                        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
};
```